# jquery keyup show/hide stay shown when backspaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, keyup

So I got this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/htz8x1no/ which basically runs on this code:

```
      $('.relevant-results').hide();

      $('#input').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
          $('.relevant-results').hide();
        } else {
          $('.relevant-results').show();
        }
      });
```

When you put more then 3 characters in the input it will show the div otherwise it will hide it. This works as expected but I would like to keep the div visible when the user removes(backspaces) a part of it.

So this `keyup` function should only run the first time the user inputs. Is it possible to do this with jQuery/JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just test to see if the input is greater than or equal to three and then show the div. No need for the logic to hide it.

```js
$('.relevant-results').hide();
      
$('#input').keyup(function() {
   if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
      $('.relevant-results').show();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
<div class="relevant-results">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: You are so right. Strange why brains most of the time pick the harder route. Thanks for showing the easier route.

Answer (score 1):

Use backspace key code like this.

```js
$('.relevant-results').hide();

$('#input').keyup(function (e) {
  if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    } else {
      $('.relevant-results').hide();
    }
  } else {
    $('.relevant-results').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
<div class="relevant-results">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: This works really nice. But I see that when you remove all the characters and then start typing again it briefly hides the div. Is it possible to remove this?